# problems with writing rows to a DataSet in Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, .net

I am new to Visual Studio 2010 and there seen very few C++ examples of anything on MSDN so would appreciate some help.

I have used the DataSet function from the ToolBox window to create a single table with three columns (for brevity I have left out two of them in the example below.

I am getting the following error:

error C3293: 'Item': use 'default' to access the default property (indexer) for class 'System::Data::DataRow'

Here is the code as generated by VS2010 instantiating the table:

```
this->GraphInput->DataSetName = L"GraphDataIn";
this->GraphInput->Tables->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Data::DataTable^ >(1) {this->RefElectInput});

//RefElectInput
this->RefElectInput->Columns->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Data::DataColumn^ >(3) {this->RefElect0Av, this->RefElect0Max, this->RefElect0Min});
this->RefElectInput->MinimumCapacity = 7;
this->RefElectInput->TableName = L"RefElecInput";
//
// RefElect0Av
//
this->RefElect0Av->ColumnName = L"RefElect0Av";
this->RefElect0Av->DataType = System::Double::typeid;
```

Here is the code where I try towrite to the row (I have only shown one column):

```
DataRow^ myRow;
myRow = RefElectInput->NewRow();
myRow->Item[L"RefElect0Av"] = peUnPackDataRec->saeRefElec0.adfRefElecAv[i];
//the error data is of type doubleoccurs here.

//other column's removed.

RefElectInput->Rows->Add(myRow);
```

I would be grateful for your assistance.

Thank you Simon

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
DataRow^ myRow;
myRow = RefElectInput->NewRow();
myRow->default[L"RefElect0Av"] = peUnPackDataRec->saeRefElec0.adfRefElecAv[i];
```